# Moving from DoubleClick Enabler.js to AdWords code amends

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-ads-api, double-click

I am new to JS and need to update a banner for a customer to work with AdWords but they don't allow Google's DoubleClick enabler.js. I need to some how replicate the following but not sure how.

It's using:

//s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js

```
// Checks if Enabler is loaded
creative.init = function () {

    creative.detectIE();
    creative.setupDOMElements();

    if (Enabler.isInitialized()) {
        creative.enablerInitHandler();
    } else {
        Enabler.addEventListener(studio.events.StudioEvent.INIT, creative.enablerInitHandler);
    }
};
/**
 * enablerInitHandler
 * Checks if page is loaded, or waits for it to load, then inits pageLoadHandler()
 */
creative.enablerInitHandler = function (event) {

    creative.domEl.tapArea.addEventListener('click', creative.exitClickHandler);

    if (Enabler.isPageLoaded()) {
        creative.pageLoadHandler();
    } else {
        Enabler.addEventListener(studio.events.StudioEvent.PAGE_LOADED, creative.pageLoadHandler);
    }
};

creative.exitClickHandler = function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    Enabler.exit("clicktrough");
    console.log("click");

};
```

Comment: Stuck in a similar boat. I've got this feedback from my client "**HTML5 ads created using DoubleClick Studio are not supported**" and my first guess is to swap out the Enabler.js script to something else, but can't seem to find it in their documentation.

Comment: Apparently removing Enabler and any calls to it fixes the validation issue. It doesn't need to be replaced by anything else - in other words, there's no  "Exit" calls necessary.

Comment: So does the Google Ads platform (formerly AdWords) automatically handle things like only loading the ad once the host page load has completed, and has been scrolled into view? Google documentation on all this is full of contradictions, what a mess!